# Store user input to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Hello I'm trying to understand how local storage works. I'm trying to take a users input and add it to local storage. I'm not sure which parameter I'm passing in wrong. Here's my code:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("todo");
const list = document.querySelector(".list-items");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userInput = document.querySelector(".userAdd").value;
  const userListItem = document.createElement("li");
  userListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput));
  list.appendChild(userListItem);
  localStorage.setItem('userListItem', userInput);
}
```

```html
<form id="todo">
  <input class="userAdd" type="text">
  <input  type="submit">
</form>
<ul class="list-items"></ul>
```

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: How do you know, the localstorage isn't set? You never retrieve the value back.

Comment: Well when I console.log(localStorage) I see that userListItem is being stored but It disappears when I refresh the page

Comment: It disappears from where? Where does your form redirect you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save your `list items` in `localStorage`, you need to keep them in an `array`. I modified your code accordingly. https://codepen.io/dasseya1/pen/qMXQmK

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("todo");
const list = document.querySelector(".list-items");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userInput = document.querySelector(".userAdd").value;
  const userListItem = document.createElement("li");
  userListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput));
  list.appendChild(userListItem);
  const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
  localStorage.setItem('userListItem', JSON.stringify(myArray));
}

const listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');


function map(arrayLike, fn) {
    var ret = [], i = -1, len = arrayLike.length;
    while (++i < len) ret[i] = fn(arrayLike[i]);
    return ret;
}

function getText(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) return node.data;
    var txt = '';
    if (node = node.firstChild) do {
        txt += getText(node);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
    return txt;
}
```

```html
<form id="todo">
  <input class="userAdd" type="text">
  <input  type="submit">
</form>
<ul class="list-items"></ul>
```

Comment: @mKe01010101 Are you satisfied?

Comment: Perfect that you. Storing them in an array is where I struggled.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine. When I refresh my page, it's still there. Test it out in your eg Chrome `console` ... Additionally, if this code is disappearing after you refresh your page, then I suggest checking your browsers **`Privacy settings`** Hope it helps.

Imagine this is your userInput data:

```
let userInput = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store - [ we would pass it like this, using -> JSON.stringify ]
    localStorage.setItem("userListItems", JSON.stringify(userInput)); 
} else {
    console.warn("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}

// Retrieve - and when we want to get the item we would use JSON.parse to give us back an array
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userListItems")));
```

**Sidenote:** If you're using `Chrome` (which I hope you do), you can press ***`CTRL + SHIFT + I`*** go to you `'Application'` tab and under `'Storage'` click on the `'Local Storage'` ... you'll find your data there and inspect it even further.

**UPDATE:** I've updated my answer to a much better version thanks to @Kaiido
**`localStorage`**  stores only strings. So in my previous answer, it would get coerced to `"one, two, three"`, but now you actually get an `array` back.

Comment: localStorage stores only strings. Your example is not the best as it will get coerced to the string `"one,two,three"`.

Comment: @Kaiido You're right, but if you leave out the `[ ]` it will only store the first value, right? So, since it's a list (to-dos) example I went with that example. I'll update my answer to include your contribution too. Cheers ;)

Comment: JSON.stringify is your friend. (remember to JSON.parse at get).

Comment: @Kaiido A great update. I actually learned something new. So, thanks. ;)